Как добавить дополнительную страницу HTML в JavaDoc?
Имеется проект, где с помощью Maven JavaDoc плагина генерируется документация. В документацию необходимо добавить дополнительные HTML страницы. В overview.html или в package-overview.html добавлять не вариант, т.к. страниц несколько и они не относятся к какому-либо конкретному пакету/классу. В параметрах конфигурации плагина не нашёл чего-либо, что решало бы задачу/проблему. Единственно, что у меня получилось, так это добавить дополнительные страницы в src/main/javadoc/resources и ссылаться на них из overview.html, но в этом случае я получаю "голую" HTML-страницу, т.е. без стилей, фреймов и т.д..
Каким образом добавить дополнительную/-ые HTML-страницы в JavaDoc?

Используемая конфигурация javadoc плагина:
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <javadocExecutable>${javadocExecutable}</javadocExecutable>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <version>true</version>
        <!-- See more about doclint syntax here:
        https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javadoc.html#additional-options-provided-by-the-standard-doclet -->
        <doclint>all,-accessibility,-missing</doclint>
        <additionalJOptions>
            <additionalJOption>-J-Duser.language=en_US</additionalJOption>
        </additionalJOptions>
        <locale>en_US</locale>
        <docfilessubdirs>true</docfilessubdirs>
        <addStylesheets>
            <addStylesheet>javadoc.css</addStylesheet>
            <addStylesheet>bootstrap-icons.min.css</addStylesheet>
        </addStylesheets>
        <bottom><![CDATA[Copyright &copy; {currentYear}, <a href="${project.organization.url}">{organizationName}<a>]]></bottom>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

overview.html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>API Overview</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Useful links</h2>
    <ul class="no-bullet">
        <li><a href="./resources/additional_page.html">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="./resources/additional_page_too.html">Two</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>


Ссылки

Maven JavaDoc плагин
Параметры конфигурации Maven JavaDoc плагина
Использование JavaDoc ресурсов

